# Create a new branch at a certain revision

Tags: mercurial

With mercurial it is easy to create a tag at a certain revision: `hg tag -r <revision> <tag-name>`. But how to create a branch at a certain revision?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Preface:** Mercurial branches are two types:

- named branch
- anonymous

### Named Branch

In order to get named branch BRANCHNAME, starting at REV

```
hg update REV
hg branch BRANCHNAME
...
hg commit
```

commit is a must, because

> the branch will not exist in the repository until the next commit

as noted in `hg help branch`

### Anonymous branch

```
hg update REV
...
hg commit
```

and current branch get additional head

---

And as a last step, use the following command to create a remote branch and push the changesets.

```
hg push --new-branch
```

Comment: problem: when doing `hg update 679; hg branch mybranch; hg commit`, the branch mybranch will still start at the tip of branch default, not at revision 679.

Comment: @Francois - check current rev after update with `hg id -n`

Answer (score 1):

You could you `hg clone -r <rev>`. From the command line help (run `hg -v help clone`):

```
- create a repository without changesets after a particular revision:

    hg clone -r 04e544 experimental/ good/
```

Comment: Clone isn't branch per se. It will (may) appear only after hg pull|push from|to SRC repo

Comment: @LazyBadger My bad, thanks for pointing that out. +1 to your answer.